# Замена значений 2-х переменных

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как заставить это работать?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a = 0;
  int b = 3;
  swap(a, b);
}

public static void swap (int x, int y){
  int tmp = x;
  x = y;
  y = tmp;
}
```

Comment: ну например для начала написать что этот код должен делать и что в нем не работает. и почему должно работать так, как ты думаешь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в коде стандартный метод замены значений двух переменных. Третья названа tmp, как и абсолютно во всех примерах и слово-название-метода swap так же говорит само за себя.

Comment: Мб http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/lang/java/java5/vol1/ch6.html поможет

Comment: Неважно что где тут написано. Я мог спокойно метод назвать `swap`, который перебирает лягушек в озере. Для нормального полноценного вопроса при нерабочем коде всегда необходимо описывать что он должен делать, что в нем не так с вашей точки зрения и почему (если планируется какое-то поведение) должно быть так

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примитивы передаются не по ссылке. В вашем коде меняются лишь локальные копии на стеке в методе `swap`.
Можно завернуть во что-то. Часто делают так:

```
public class IntRef { 
    public int value; 

    public IntRef (int val) {
        value = val;
    }
}
```

Тогда ваш код будет таким:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  IntRef a = new IntRef(0);
  IntRef b = new IntRef(3);
  swap(a,b);
}

public static void swap (IntRef x, IntRef y){
    int tmp = x.value;
    x.value = y.value;
    y.value = tmp;
}
```

Comment: тогда уж проще Integer тип делать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да. Но я именно концептуальный подход хотел показать.

Comment: .....м, хорошо)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, и чем же Integer поможет?

Comment: @Qwertiy `Integer ` никак. А `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` поможет, так как мутабельный тип ^^

Comment: Большое спасибо, этот пример отлично помог разобраться

Answer (score 3):

В джаве нет передачи переменных по ссылке, поэтому сделать swap двух переменных невозможно.

Можно менять поля у объектов, но получается, что вместо двух переменных нужно иметь 2 поля (2 поля у одного объекта, либо по 1 полю у двух объектов), но это явно не то, что имело бы смыл делать.